# How to check query have results in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, search

i used custom category search in  wordpress using below code.

```
<?php

function mySearchFilter($query) {

    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'demotheme') { 
   $post_type = "dtheme";
    }
    if ($query->is_search) {        

            $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
    };

    return $query;
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
?>
```

in the above `$query->set('post_type', $post_type);` has return set of results. here i need to check if it is return empty result,
i need to place,

`$query->set('post_type', "dplugins");`

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers,

i use below one for both, it works great.

```
<?php

function mySearchFilter($query) {    
    if ($query->is_search) {        
        $query->set('post_type', array('post','page','attachment','dtheme','dplugins'));
    };
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result set is an array you can simply use this code

```
$res = $query->set('post_type', $post_type);

if ($res)
    // add your code here!
```

also there is some nice functions to check the return value "is_null()", "isset()", "is_array()".

Answer (score 0):

I expanded upon MJ.Ahmadi's answer and plugged it into your code.

```
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'demotheme') { 
        $post_type = "dtheme";
    }
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $result = $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
    };
    if($result){
        return $query;
    } else{
        $result = $query->set('post_type', "dplugins");
        if($result){
            return $query;
        }
    }
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
?>
```